# I want plot1 appear on tab1 and plot2 appear on tab2

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I have a static shinydashboard that has two tabs. Currently, plot1 and plot2 appear on both tab1 and tab2.

I want plot1 to only appear on tab1. I want plot2 to only appear on tab2.

Please let me know if you need more information.

```
First plot data: 
structure(list(gender = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("female", 
"male"), class = "factor"), subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("math", "reading", "writing"), class = "factor"), 
    avg_score = c(63.6332046332046, 68.7282157676349, 72.6081081081081, 
    65.4730290456432, 72.4671814671815, 63.3112033195021)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

Second plot data:
structure(list(race_ethnicity = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), subject = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("math", 
"reading", "writing"), class = "factor"), avg_score = c(61.6292134831461, 
63.4526315789474, 64.4639498432602, 67.3625954198473, 73.8214285714286, 
64.6741573033708, 67.3526315789474, 69.1034482758621, 70.030534351145, 
73.0285714285714, 62.6741573033708, 65.6, 67.8275862068966, 70.1450381679389, 
71.4071428571429)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L
))




ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Student Performance"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Demographics", tabName = "demographics", icon = icon("id-card")),
      menuItem("Programs", tabName = "programs", icon = icon("folder")))),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "demographics",
          fluidRow(box(plotOutput("p1")),
      tabItem(tabName = "programs",
          fluidRow(box(plotOutput(("p2"))))))))))

server <- function(input, output){
output$p1 <- renderPlot({ggplot(df1, aes(x = gender, y = avg_score))+
    geom_col(aes(fill = subject), width = 0.7)})

output$p2 <- renderPlot({ggplot(df2, aes(x = race_ethnicity, y = avg_score))+
    geom_col(aes(fill = subject), width = 0.7)})}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may just be your parentheses placement in your UI. This seemed to work:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Student Performance"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Demographics", tabName = "demographics", icon = icon("id-card")),
      menuItem("Programs", tabName = "programs", icon = icon("folder")))),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # Demographic tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "demographics",
              fluidRow(box(plotOutput("p1")))
              ),

      # Programs tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "programs",
              fluidRow(box(plotOutput("p2")))
              )
    )
  )
)
```